# How to generate PDF in Hebrew? currently the PDF is generated empty

Tags: itext

I'm using iTextSharp 5.5.13 and when i try to generate the PDF with Hebrew it comes out empty. 
this is my code: I'm i doing something wrong?

```
    public byte[] GenerateIvhunPdf(FinalIvhunSolution ivhun)
    {
        byte[] pdfBytes;
        using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, mem);
            writer.PageEvent = new MyHeaderNFooter();
            document.Open();
            var font = new 
            Font(BaseFont.CreateFont("C:\\Downloads\\fonts\\Rubik-Light.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 14);
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph("פסקת פתיחה")
            {
                Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT

            };
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2)
            {
                RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL
            };
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("מזהה", font));
            cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.BLACK;
            table.AddCell(cell);

            document.Add(p);
            document.Add(table);
            document.Close();
            pdfBytes = mem.ToArray();

        }
        return pdfBytes;
    }
```

The PDF comes out blank

Comment: You create the `Paragraph p` using the default font. That default font will only include a Latin-1-like character set. Thus, no surprise that `p` comes out blank. Concerning the phrase in the `PdfPCell cell` I'm not sure... does `Rubik-Light.ttf` contain Hebrew characters?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Yes, Rubik-Light.ttf contains Hebrew characters.

Comment: Is it freely available?

Comment: The font? Yes.i add the font to the paragraph as well but it still does not work.

Comment: Where is it available? To allow reproducing the issue...

Comment: https://fonts.google.com/selection?selection.family=Rubik

Comment: #mkl  dud you find it?

Comment: Not yet - I've not yet being away my work station.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a few details of your code, and now I get this:

[image: screen shot]

My changes:

#### Embedding the font

As I don't have Rubik installed on my system, I have to embed the font into the PDF to have a chance to see anything. Thus, I replaced `BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED` by `BaseFont.EMBEDDED` when creating the `var font`:

```
var font = new Font(BaseFont.CreateFont("Rubik-Light.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED), 14);
```

#### Making the `Paragraph` kind of work

You create the `Paragraph p` without specifying a font. Thus, a default font with default encoding is used. The default encoding is **WinAnsiEncoding** which is Latin1-like, so no Hebrew characters can be represented. I added your Rubik font instance to the `Paragraph p` creation:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("פסקת פתיחה", font)
{
    Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT
};
```

Et voilà, the writing appears.

*iText developers often have communicated that in iText 5.x and earlier right-to-left scripts are only supported properly in certain contexts, e.g. in tables, but not in others like paragraphs immediately added to the document. As your `Paragraph p` is added immediately to the `Document document`, its letters appear in the wrong order in the output.*

#### Making the `PdfPTable` work

You defined the `PdfPTable table` to have two columns (`new PdfPTable(2)`) but then you added only one cell. Thus, `table` contains not even a single complete row. iText, therefore, draws nothing when it is added to the document.

I changed the definition of `table` to have a single column only:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1)
{
    RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL
};
```

Furthermore, I commented out the line setting the cell background to black because usually it is difficult to read black on black:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("מזהה", font));
//cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.BLACK;
table.AddCell(cell);
```

And again the writing appears.

#### Properly downloading the font

Another possible obstacle is that when downloading the font from the URL you gave — https://fonts.google.com/selection?selection.family=Rubik — one can see in the customization tab of the selection drawer that by default only Latin characters are included in the download, in particular not Hebrew ones:

[image: Screenshot]

I tested with a font file I downloaded with all language options enabled:

[image: Screenshot, all selected]

Comment: Amazing,  thank you very much I really appreciate your detailed answer. I'll check it as soon as I'm near my laptop and return an answer here. Again, thank you mkl